# Error in dired-find-file-place when saving

Tags: dired, error, xemacs, save

I've been an Emacs user for 30 years. This week I'm switching to a new machine with Ubuntu 21.10 installed.

Now when I save a file, it always errors out with the error message: "Error in dired-find-file-place" (nothing more, nothing less).  In half the cases, the file is then NOT saved, in the other half of the cases it seems to work.

I'm using Xemacs21.

Using strace, I see the emacs process rename the original file to the backup myfile~ . Then it opens the directory and reads the 10 files. And then it sends the error message to the X server.  The file save succeeds when the rename has already happened on the previous attempt so this time the file is saved and "Wrote myfile" is displayed for a few miliseconds and then directory read and error. Somehow its getting weird results from the directory listing?

I have now also determined that this happens only on SOME buffers, not all.

Comment: You say *"it always errors out with that error message"*. What error message? Is `Error in dired-find-file-place when saving` the actual error message - nothing more than that?

Comment: Yeah, more or less. "when saving" is my description of when it happens. So the full error message is: "error in dired-file-file-place". Hmm. Just to make sure I didn't make a spelling error in the error message, I redid it. Turns out another file/buffer does NOT have the problem. So: Some files/buffers have this issue, others do not.

Comment: Please edit your question to put all such info in it. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.